# Проблема с соединением SQLite. Почему появляется эта ошибка?

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, sqlite, unity3d-android

Сама ошибка:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No connection associated with this
>   command at Mono.Data.SQite.SQLiteCommand.InitializeForReader ()
>   [0x00031]

Появляется только при тестировании приложения на телефоне, при запуске в Unity всё работает.

Код:

```
    public void connection()  
    {
        try
        {
            if (Application.platform != RuntimePlatform.Android)  
            {
                path = Application.dataPath + "/Items.bytes"; 
            }
            else
            {
                path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/StreamingAssets/Items.bytes"; 
                if (!File.Exists(path))
                {
                    WWW load = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + "Items.bytes");
                    while (!load.isDone) { }
                    File.WriteAllBytes(path, load.bytes);
                }
            }

            con_db = new SqliteConnection("URI=file:" + path);
            con_db.Open();
            if (con_db.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                text.text = path.ToString() + " IsConnected"; 
            }



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            text.text = ex.ToString(); 
        }
    }

    private void Disconnect()
    {
        con_db.Close();
    }

    public void SetDB() 
    {
        connection();
        try
        {
            Item_ID = IDField.text.ToString();
            Item_Name = NameField.text.ToString();
            Item_Count = CountField.text.ToString();
            Item_Desc = DescField.text.ToString();
            Stat_Text = StatText.text.ToString();


            cmd_db = new SqliteCommand("INSERT INTO Items(Item_ID,Item_Name,Item_Count,Item_Desc,Item_Status) VALUES('" + Item_ID + "','" + Item_Name + "','" + Item_Count + "','" + Item_Desc + "','" + Stat_Text + "')", con_db);
            cmd_db.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            text.text = ex.ToString();
        }
        Disconnect();
    }
```

Как я понял, такая ошибка возникает, если в команде нету ссылки на подключение. Но здесь эта ссылка есть

Comment: Есть предположение, что ошибка возникает в методе `connection` и выбивается исключение. Потом это исключение перезатирается повторным исключение уже в `SetDB` т.к. в функции `connection` инициализация подключения не была выполнена. Попробуйте посмотреть через += список ошибок: `text.text += ex.ToString();` .

Comment: И правда. Почему-то не находит путь к самой базе данных.

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/storage/emullated/0/Android/data/com.NetComp.SQLite/files/StreamingAssets/Items.bytes".

Достаточно странно, не так давно тестировал, и всё работало. 
Никаких серьёзных изменений с тех пор в код не вносил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема заключается в том, что вы работаете с базой данных (хотя тут не важно бд это или какой-то другой ассет) и пытаетесь ее изменять *внутри пакета*.

Суть в том, что когда Unity собирает все свои ресурсы (не исходники, а какие-либо ассеты), она формирует большой бинарный файл, который намертво зашивается в пакет приложения и изменить пакет приложения вы не можете. В случае с Android вы получаете apk (или jar архив) и менять его содержимое не получится, как минимум, потому что не знаете как работать с этим бинарным объектом.

Вы используете [Application.dataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html), который доступен для модификации и чтения только в редакторе Unity (тот самый будущий огромный бинарник в собранном билде) и пытаете прочитать файл. Только после сборки в один бинарник вся иерархия директорий и объектов перестает существовать в том виде, как отображает редактор Unity. В редакторе Unity это ожидаемо работает, потому что ресурсы не собраны в один большой бинарный файл, вы имеете к ним неограниченный доступ, и все отлично работает. При работе уже собранного приложения вы не имеете доступ к ассетам, которые лежат внутри этого огромного бинарного файла, у вас есть доступ только к тем ассетам, что лежат в папке Resources, либо к внешней папке.

Если вы хотите менять значения внутри вашей базы данных, то вам нужно поместить ее в [Application.persistantDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) (внешняя папка приложения). Это директория к которой у вас будет доступ для чтения и записи на всех платформах уже после сборки проекта. Явно "руками" переместить туда файл у вас не получится. Но это можно реализовать следующим образом:

1. Создаете бд в вашем проекте и кладете ее в папку Resources
2. При запуске приложения проверяете, есть ли ваша бд в `Application.persistantDataPath`
3. Если ее там нет - кодом скопируйте ее в эту папку и работайте с бд, лежащей в 
   `Application.persistantDataPath`

На тему подключения бд к проекту с возможностью модификации содержимого бд есть неплохой [тутор](https://habr.com/ru/post/442954/). Если предложенный вариант решения проблемы будет работать на Android, но испортит работу в редакторе Unity, в туторе предлагается оставить бд в `Application.dataPath` для редактора Unity и в `Application.persistantDataPath` для мобильных сборок.

Comment: `path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/StreamingAssets/Items.bytes"; //Путь для Android
                if (!File.Exists(path))
                {
                    WWW load = new WWW("jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/" + "Items.bytes");
                    while (!load.isDone) { }
                    File.WriteAllBytes(path, load.bytes);
                }`
Я здесь это и делаю

Comment: да, только пытаетесь загрузить свою бд все-равно из Application.dataPath. Так не получится, потому что читать и писать из Application.dataPath нельзя. Используйте Resources, как я и написал в ответе

Comment: Да, вот только теперь при запуске в редакторе появляется такая ошибка:  

C:/Users/User/AppData/LocalLow/NettComp/SQLite/Items.bytes IsConnectedMono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite error
no such table: Items  
Хотя я точно знаю, что таблица с таким именем есть

Comment: посмотрите тутор - [на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/442954/). Вопрос-то у вас про андроид, а не про win редактор